# path should be string, bytes or os.PathLike, not InMemoryUploadedFile

Tags: python, pdf, xpdf

In django I get the file uploaded by the user with `input_pdf = request.FILES['pdf']` and I want to extract fiel text with `pdftextract` library with `pdf = XPdf(input_pdf)` but it gives an error: `TypeError: _getfullpathname: path should be string, bytes or os.PathLike, not InMemoryUploadedFile`. How should I get the path of the user uploaded file or how can I use `pdftextract` with the data type `InMemoryUploadedFile`.
I must say that for local files `pdftextract` extract text with the following code:

```
from pdftextract import XPdf
file_path = "examples/pubmed_example.pdf"
pdf = XPdf(file_path)
txt = pdf.to_text()
print(txt)
```

Comment: Your actual code that is giving the error would be much more relevant than code that works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to decode a PDF file object, but XPdf expects a file path. You should save your file to a path on disk (you could open a file path as write and read your uploaded file to it) and then call XPdf on the path.